# callback issue with fb sdk for unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, callback, sdk

everybody. I have the following issue with using the newest Unity SDK of Facebook.

I wanna encourage my user to share pictures representing their highest score by returning them some little gifts after successful sharing. So I need the FacebookDelegate >IGraphResult< callback definitely. It works fine except one point:

If it is first time the user is asked to login in order to grant the "publish_action" permission to my App, everything is fine. I have tested through the whole process, even if I chose "cancel" instead of "share" at the very last step(after Login), the **"result.Cancelled"** from the above mentioned callback function is assigned with **"true"**, so that user will get nothing, for they did not really share.

BUT! if the first sharing has been completed, and my App stays logged in with "Publish_Action" permission(which means the user does not have to give their username and password again the next time they wanna share), every time I tried to share and cancelled at the last step(this means I did not really share), though, the **"result.Cancelled"** is **always** assigned with **"false"** so that the gifts are always granted despite of success or non-success of sharing.

so my question is:

1, can anyboby give me an advice to fix the **result.Cancelled** assignment issue?

2, is there possibility to go around the **"result.Cancelled"**(for example: maybe there is something like "result.done" or "result.finished" which just refers to the success of an action explicitly?)

Thank all of you guys in advance! your answer will save my life and be remembered for 1000 years!!

Comment: You are not allowed to reward users for sharing in any way. Please go read Facebook's [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

Comment: We also faced something similar, but that was a long time ago, see the bug i reported here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1273130986031219/
you can try to get the raw result (.RawResult property) to see if it contains information about cancelling. if it does, you can modify the Facebook SDK to handle that case.